# How can I split up a large impl over multiple files?

Tags: rust

I really don't like monolithic implementations of the functions for a class (in C++ speak). In that language I can split things up as I like; in Rust there are strict rules about what goes in what files.

I have about 2000 lines (no comments/ docs) of `impl` for a struct. Logically they can be broken up into different sets; functions for managing aspect A, functions for managing aspect B, ... They all noodle on the `struct`'s data big time, so chopping the `struct` up further wont help.

I saw in one answer that you can have

```
// in thing.rs

struct Thing{
.......
}

impl Thing{
  fn1
  fn2
}
```

```
// in more_thing.rs

use crate::thing::*;
impl Thing{
  fn3,
  fn4
}
```

```
// in lib.rs

mod thing;
mod more_thing;
```

This works, almost (I was surprised it worked at all). Its a kind of half way house. The problem is that for the methods in more_thing.rs I have to declare the fields of `Thing` all `pub`. Which is doable but not great. Are there any other options?

I know I can limit the `pub` scope but still it blows encapsulation.

Comment: In the first place, 2k LoC doesn't seem big enough to split up for that reason alone... 10k would in my opinion be pushing it but frankly some things are just big by their nature. Secondly, I find it curious that you consider the monolithic implementation a problem, but not the fact that the struct itself is apparently a monolith. You say its data can't be usefully subdivided, but it has a number of "aspects" to its behavior that are quasi-independent - that suggests to me a likely violation of SRP.

Comment: @trentcl The struct has about 10 fields, its a pdp11 cpu, aspects are, stack management, instructions, memory access, exception handling. External io, device mgmt .. already offloaded to different struct/Impls. It’s just a lot of code operating on a small amount of data

Comment: Exactly my point: it's a monolithic `struct` with a lot of behavior. Putting it all in one file doesn't make it *more* monolithic, and splitting the implementation (which is all tightly coupled to the same data) over a bunch of smaller files is just window dressing IMO. I would consider splitting the implementation of a single struct over multiple files to be a distant *third* option after (1) refactoring so the struct isn't a monolith and (2) just putting it in a big file. That said, Rust does let you do it (see my answer).

Comment: pub(crate) could be the thing to do. That way you can split the file as you like, but external users don't get to call your internal functions.

Answer (score 39):

All non-`pub` items in a module are still visible in its submodules. Just make `more_thing`  a submodule of `thing` instead of a sibling. You can do this by putting it in a directory named `thing`, and putting the `mod` declaration inside `thing.rs`:

```
// thing.rs (or thing/mod.rs; see below)
pub struct Thing {
    field: i32,
}

// Note the lack of `pub`: `more` is only an implementation detail
mod more;
```

```
// thing/more.rs
use super::Thing;

impl Thing {
    // Although it is defined in a non-`pub` module, this method will be visible anywhere
    // `Thing` is because it is marked `pub` and is a member of `Thing`. You can use
    // `pub(crate)` or `pub(super)` instead to get different levels of visibility, or
    // leave it private and it will only be available in the current module (thing::more)
    pub fn field(&self) -> i32 {
        // because more is a submodule of thing, non-`pub` members are visible here.
        self.field
    }
}
```

If you wish to keep all the `Thing`-related files in the `thing` directory, you can rename `thing.rs` to the special filename `thing/mod.rs` and it will work in exactly the same way.

Comment: I think this is actually a better answer than mine. Also maybe you could add that `thing.rs` could also be `thing/mod.rs` to keep it in the same directory?

Comment: @trentcl - ty. I know it makes no functional difference but I just find it easier to have a number of smaller files, my tiny brain likes tiny things.

Comment: i have struct in cpu/mod.rs along with one set of impl. Another set of impl in cpu/instructions.rs. Those methods in instruction.rs have private access to the struct data (good) but the methods in mod.rs cannot call those in instructions.rs (not so good)

Comment: @pm100 That's because submodules are external :(. I guess you could mark them `pub(super)`, which IMO is not too bad. If you think of modules like a tree, you can only access downward for public items.

Comment: @pm100 That's right, you have to mark things `pub` (or `pub(...)`) to make them visible "up" the hierarchy. That's why my example uses `pub fn`.

Comment: Yes, good suggestion. Make the common private functions in the base module (mod.rs), and then, sub modules can expose their public and have their own private just for them.

Comment: allowing impl blocks to be spread across files almost gives inheritance-like capabilities.  Is there any way to do this with the struct definition -- i.e. break it up so that fields can be added in other files?

Comment: @Chad I don't think there is anything particularly inheritance-like about structs - there is no "1 class per file" rule in Rust, so the `impl` in another file is just an `impl`, not a different structure entirely. Note that `impl`s themselves have no privacy or visibility; all `impl`s for a given struct are usable anywhere. To achieve something like data "inheritance" in Rust, you would probably use generics (e.g. `struct Base<Derived> { parent_field: String, child_fields: Derived }`) but that is only one way of interpreting "inheritance".

Answer (score 1):

All methods are private by default in Rust, which means they are only accessible in the scope of their containing *module* (which is never larger than a file), in this case `thing.rs`. `thing.rs` is just as remote to `more_thing.rs` as any libraries and external code; it may as well be a separate crate. In essence, you are trying to declare a private method on an external item, which of course fails.

However, this can be a bit confusing because when it comes to orphan rules, you can always implement traits for any item in the same *crate*, not just the same *module*. This is because trait implementations are always public (as long as you can access both the trait and the item implementing it; the actual orphan rules are a bit more complicated but this is the basic idea).

In essence: trait implementations are public, but method implementations are private by default. In order to implement public things you need at least public access, and in order to implement private things you need private access.

Instead, one solution is to simply declare a function that takes your item as an argument. For example, in `more_thing.rs`:

```rust
use super::thing::Thing;

fn foo(thing: &Thing) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -3):

rust supports multiple impl blocks.

```rust
in thing.rs

struct Thing {
.......
}

impl Thing {
  fn1
  fn2
}

include!(./thing_2.rs)
```

```rust
// thing_2.rs
impl Thing {
  fn3
  fn4
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the primary issue, which is that the file is huge. OP mentioned not wanting 2000 lines in one file.

Comment: What is the practical use of splitting these impl blocks?

Comment: @Luxalpa To have different trait constraints on the different functions. For example, the `impl` for `fn1` and `fn2` might have no constrain, while the other `impl` might have `Thing: Copy`.